# various usages of the adverb not

Tags: adverbs

Was it ***not*** his Self, his small, fearful and proud Self, with which he had wrestled for so many years, but which had always conquered him again, which appeared each time again and again, which robbed him of happiness and filled him with fear? Was it not this which had finally died today in the wood by this delightful river?

Would you please in a more readily way tell me if I have properly explain the following?

From my point of view, such a usage of using the adverb not-- that is, after subject-- shows emphasis or the context is literary. S, the following could mean the same thing:

does not he go there?

does he not go there?

The ***specific*** question: what is the difference between the following, and would you refer me to a accredited-- autharetive-- site in order that I could get it better?

was it ***not*** something...?

was ***not*** it something...?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is the question here? Uncontracted *"Does not he care?"* is a stilted / antiquated / non-idiomatic usage in most contexts, so feasibly if you *did* encounter a current instance you might assume the purpose was *emphasis* (unless you knew it was from a non-native speaker, in which case it's far more likely to be just a mistake). One effect of using ***not*** in the initial citation above is to imply more strongly that the narrator/subject *is inclined to believe* the speculation is in fact ***true***. But it's as much a matter of style as semantics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does not he go there?

Does he not go there?

In modern English, when you form negative interrogative sentences, you use "not" either after the subject in formal English or before the subject in a contracted form in conversational English.  The use of "not" in an uncontractrd form  before the subject, as pointed out by FumbleFingers, is outdated and rarely used in modern English. So, normally formed sentences are as follows:

Doesn't he go there?

Does he not go there?

Was it not something?

Wasn't it something?

Pls consult Oxford University Press - A Practical English Grammar, Chapter 10.